# Android: Generate image from dynamic view

Tags: android

I want to generate chart dynamically, and save the chart as image for later use in the application,
Need not to display the chart on the screen, 
I can generate the chart using `AFreeChart` Library, The chart is actually a sub view of `View` class,
I want to get bitmap from the view using the following code, but the method `getDrawingCache()` always returns null,

```
    // Retrieve the chart generated using AFreeChart Library
    // PressureChart is a sub view of View class
     PressureChart mView = new PressureChart(this);

     mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     mView.buildDrawingCache(true);
     Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getDrawingCache());
     mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```

Comment: show the below code its perfectly run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u want to get the bitmap like this.. its perfectly work
u need the pass the view in method like.

`Bitmap mBitmap = getBitmapFromView(viewname);`

and then use the bitmap to store image..

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    // Define a bitmap with the same size as the view

    int FixWidth = 800;
    int FixHeight = 800;
    int bit_width = 0;
    int bit_height = 0;

    bit_width = mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    bit_height = mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

    if (bit_width > FixWidth) {
        bit_width = FixWidth;
    }

    if (bit_height > FixHeight) {
        bit_height = FixHeight;
    }

    float ratio = Math.min((float) 800 / bit_width, (float) 800 / bit_height);
    int width = Math.round((float) ratio * bit_width);
    int height = Math.round((float) ratio * bit_height);

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width * 2, height * (int)2.5f, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    // Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        // has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        // does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    // return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: What is this variable `mImageView` in the above code?

Comment: @ShahulHameed just take the width and height on imageview nothing as.. u need the give static value in width & height.

Comment: This solution worked for me after modifying some code on `View` subclass, in my case `PressureChart` class by hard coding value for `Dimension`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this..

Add that Chart `view` on `FrameLayout` and then use..

```
    feamelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bm = f.getDrawingCache();
```

to save the image..

Answer (score 0):

Put some delay(1/2 seconds) before 
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getDrawingCache());
mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache

using some timer this will help in most of the cases as we try to capture image before it is prepared.

Your code would look like

```
// Retrieve the chart generated using AFreeChart Library
    // PressureChart is a sub view of View class
     PressureChart mView = new PressureChart(this);

     mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     mView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // this code will be executed after 2 seconds  
                 Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getDrawingCache());
                 mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache     
        }

}, 2000);
```